# maven install and deploy 3rd party dependencies with simple command line

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

We have a number of third party dependencies that aren't hosted anywhere. For each of these we have a jar file that we'd like to be able to install and/or deploy to our repository. Some of the jar files have their own dependencies and we also need to declare these.

We've made pom.xml files for each jar file that declare the groupId, artifactId, dependencies, etc. These pom.xml files all have a common parent pom that declares some of the common info (e.g. `<repositories>` and `<distributionManagement>`).

I'd like to be able to install or deploy these dependencies with something as simple as `mvn install` and `mvn deploy` (or maybe `mvn install:install-file` and `mvn deploy:deploy-file`) and have all the necessary properties for these commands (`artifactId`, `repositoryId`, etc.) be read from the pom.xml files.

To get this to work, at least for deploying, I tried putting the following in my parent pom:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <file>${jarfile}</file>
        <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
        <repositoryId>our-id</repositoryId>
        <url>our-url</url>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and then having each of the child poms define the `jarfile` property. That allows me to run `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy all the child pom artifacts. Presumably I could do something similar to get `mvn install:install-file` to work.

But with this approach, I'm unable to release the parent pom (which I must do since the child poms depend on it), and if I try to `mvn release:perform` on the parent pom, I get errors like:

```
Cannot override read-only parameter: pomFile
```

I feel like I'm probably going about this the wrong way. All I really want to do is:

- Put the common code for all the third party jars in one shared parent pom
- Write an additional minimal pom for each third party jar
- Be able to run something like `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` without having to specify all those complicated command line properties

How can I best accomplish that?

**Edit:** Made it clearer above that ideally I'd like to be able to run something as simple as `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` and not have to specify properties on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that allows me to run just `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` and have the jar file installed to the local or remote repository. Inspired by [a post to the maven-users list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200907.mbox/%3C88c1b40907012241x67f294e6yccd256dc7c9a78a2@mail.gmail.com%3E) and using the [build-helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/), in the parent pom, I have:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Attach the jar file to the artifact -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${artifactId}-${version}.jar</file>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

And then in the child poms, I have:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Some of the pieces of this that initially tripped me up:

- The `attach-artifact` execution should be under `<pluginManagement>` so it doesn't get executed if you `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` the parent pom.
- The children need to specify the `build-helper-maven-plugin` under the build plugins so that code from the parent `<pluginManagement>` gets run.
- The children have to be declared as having `<packaging>pom</packaging>` because you can't add a jar to an artifact if it has the same name as the artifact.

The only downside I see to this approach is that the artifact gets deployed as type `pom` instead of type `jar`. But I haven't seen any real consequences of that.

Answer (score 2):

When Maven is missing a dependency, it will give you an error in it's output that contains the command line to issue to add the jar to a remote repository.  That command line will automatically create a POM for you and upload the two together.  Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Using this facility, if I know that I have a dependency with no remote repository representation, I usually just go ahead and define it in my build with the GAV that I want, run the build once, then look at the build errors.  Copy out the command for the deployment, then run that command.  You'll want to make sure that you have the `<repository>` elements set up properly in the parent POM plus also set up corresponding `<server>` elements in your `settings.xml` with the repository upload password.  Other than that, you should be good to go.

I would add that you should check out Nexus before getting to far.  It's worth the hassle to set up now!  :-)

Comment: Sorry, what's a GAV? And I don't think the command line that Maven gives as an error is going to solve my problem here - how can Maven know what dependencies that jar file has without me also writing a pom for it?

Comment: It'a an abbreviation for "Group, Artifact, Version".  When you define the GAV for a dependency that is not already in a remote repo (either central or one defined in a `<repository>`, it generates that command line as a part of the error report.  Try it!

Comment: Yes, I see that it generates a command line like `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -Dversion=... -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]`. But it doesn't know what that dependencies that jar has. And since the url and repositoryId are common for all the 3rd party dependencies I have, I want to just declare those once in a parent pom and not have to remember them every time.

Comment: Ah!  I understand your concern now.  In that case, yes, define your dependency's POM, then use `-DpomFile=[pom]` to associate it with the above upload command.  When you do that, you can avoid specifying `-DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -Dversion=... -Dpackaging=jar` on the command line.

Comment: Will I have to specify the `-Durl and -DrepositoryId`?

Comment: Yes, it's all documented at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. As I said in the original post, I'm trying to avoid having to specify any of these things at the command line. The goal is to be able to type just `mvn deploy` or `mvn deploy:deploy-file` or something like that.

Comment: IMHO, this is trying to solve the wrong problem.  Creating a shell script that an administrator keeps around in case the repository gets deleted is one thing, but most installations code their POMs with the assumption that repository integrity can be taken for granted between builds.

Comment: I disagree that you never have to redeploy a jar. I just had to redeploy a jar last night because I found some additional dependencies that the jar was silently depending on at runtime. And of course, I'm trying to make it easier for me to add new third-party dependencies as well. Your approach means that each time I want to redeploy a jar or add a new third party dependency, I have to fill in a complicated command line with a series of properties (eg. url and repositoryId) that *are already declared in the pom*. I'd rather the command be something simple that everyone can easily remember.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem in my work:

> Now I have a target.jar (it has a dependencies list : a.jar, b.jar, c.jar...), I want to use `mvn install:install-file` to put it into my local repo, but when I run the command blow

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/username/.../target.jar -DgroupId=com.cnetwork.relevance  -DartifactId=target  -Dversion=1.0.0
```

but when I use it  I found there are many error, the jar which use target.jar cannot find `a.jar`, `b.jar`, `c.jar`, such as:

```
com.cnetwork.a does not exist
com.cnetwork.b does not exist
com.cnetwork.c does not exist
```

Then I went to `~/.m2/repository/.../target/1.0.0/target.pom` to find the pom file of the target, but nothing in it!

```
...
<groupId>com.cnetwork.relevance</groupId>
<artifactId>target</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
....
# no dependencies about a/b/c.jar !!!
```

This is what going wrong, the `install:file -Dfile -DgroupId -D..` does not add dependencies into pom, I correct the answer by this method

1. if you already `have this maven project source`, just install it into local repo

   `mvn clean install`
2. if you `have the jar and the pom of it`, install jar with pom

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/.../.../target.jar -DpomFile=/.../../target.pom`
3. if you `don't have a pom with target jar`, write one and use upper command.
4. if you cannot recover the pom file of it, may be you should give up.